# Shortcut key to restart render

Tags: rendering, shortcut

I have been searching for a way to get the F12 key to restart a rendering (essentially stop the current and then start another).  My workflow gets to a point where I am making small changes and want to see them rendered within 5 or 10 passes before setting up a robust rendering.
In Preferences I can find the setting for the F12 key for starting a render under Screen - Render and it uses the identifier "render.render".  When we hit Esc to stop a render, it appears that the identifier "Stop this job" is triggered, but that identifier is not available to set up a new hot key.
All in all, it would be useful for me if I could set the F12 key to both stop the current job and restart the render.  If this is not possible, I can live with hitting the Esc key and then F12.
Many thanks to anyone who can share some advice.

Comment: Why not use viewport rendering? I don't think it's possible to set up a single hotkey for stopping and starting another render.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Viewport rendering won't show items that are set to "render only" for workflow optimization or things like material displacement or some geometry node settings

Comment: i would recommend using loom - a free add-on which also renders in background (which is quicker anyway) and won't hurt your computer performance too much. And it has a lot of more features which are really helpful.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I'll take a look at Loom

Comment: It really doesn't seem to be possible. There is no operator for stopping a render in Blender. When you press Esc render.render() operator stops itself. I think the add-on suggestion is most promising as a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Martynas - I had that same thought about there being no operator for stopping. Confirmed :)  I'll see if I can get Loom integrated into my workflow.